# C++ Socket Connection automatically establishing?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am currently programming a C++ module that creates a socket server thread, which polls the accept() function every 1ms. I have a test module that spoofs a client connection that is also running. The test module initiates the creation of the server thread. After the thread is created and verified to be running, the client runs the connect() command as a test. My code states that a connection was established, returning a 0 on the connect command. However, the accept() running in my server thread never receives the connection.

The server is bound to accepting any IP:50000, and the client is not bound, but has 127.0.0.1:50000 set as its destination. Is my Linux environment automatically accepting this connection?

Here is the code for my server's socket:

```
int nSocket;
int nOn = 1;
int nControl;
struct sockaddr_in  sServerAddress;

nSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if(nSocket < 0)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create socket\n";
}
if(setsockopt(nSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &nOn, sizeof(int)) < 0)
{
    std::cout << "failed to set socket option\n";
}
nControl = fcntl(nSocket, F_GETFL);
if(fcntl(nSocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK | nControl) < 0)
{
    std::cout << "set not blocking failed\n";
}

memset(&sServerAddress, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
sServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
sServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
sServerAddress.sin_port = htons(mtListenPort);

if(bind(nSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sServerAddress, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
{
    std::cout << errno << "bind failed\n";
}

if(listen(nSocket, MAXPENDING) < 0)
{
    std::cout << "listen failed\n";
}
```

Here is the code for my test client's socket:

```
int nSocket;

nSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if(nSocket < 0)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create socket\n";
}

struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_aton(LOCAL_HOST, &serverAddress.sin_addr);
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(LISTEN_PORT00);
char msg[] = "Hello World.";

usleep(10000);

if (connect(nSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0)
{
    std::cout << errno << "Could not connect to the server.\n";
}

usleep(10000);

if (sendto(nSocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0)
{
    std::cout << errno << "Could not send data to the server.\n";
}
```

Here is a small part of the thread that runs the accept code.

```
while(mbListening)
{
    nMessengerSocket = accept(mnSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sClientAddr, &tClientAddrLength);
    if(nMessengerSocket >= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Accepted connection from " << inet_ntoa(sClientAddr.sin_addr) << std::endl;
        mnConnections++;
        mbListening = false;
    }
    mThreadRunningTime++;
    usleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `accept()`?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I am calling that in a loop running in the thread. I'll update the code.

Comment: Don't poll every 1ms! What on earth are you doing that for? Use a blocking socket or select!

Comment: You don't show complete code. Make sure `tClientAddrLength` is initialized to `sizeof sClientAddr` before calling `accept()`. That is a common error.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty new at sockets. I was kind of basing my code off of an example that a coworker had shared with me. I believe his reasoning for it was so that we can accept multiple connections.. but that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Also, you silently ignore `accept` errors. You should examine the error code because it tells you what went wrong.

Comment: Maxim, that was it. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `tClientAddrLength` is initialized to `sizeof sClientAddr` before calling `accept()`. That is a common error.

Don't silently ignore errors. Examine the error code in `errno` because it tells you what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `sendto`? That's for UDP... Use `send`.

Also, check if the port is free:

```
telnet localhost 50000

netstat -a
```